# How to convert format date from MM/DD/YYYY to YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00.000Z in Python

Tags: python, pandas, date

I used `pandas` to create a list of dictionaries. The following codes is how I create the list:

```
sheetwork = client.open('RMA Daily Workload').sheet1
list_of_work = sheetwork.get_all_records()
dfr = pd.DataFrame(list_of_work, columns = ['date' , 'value']) 
rnow = dfrnow.to_dict('records')
```

The following is the output of my list:

```
rnow = 
[{'date': '01/02/2020', 'value': 13}, 
{'date': '01/03/2020', 'value': 2}, 
{'date': '01/06/2020', 'value': 5},
...
{'date': '01/07/2020', 'value': 6}]
```

I want to change the date format from MM/DD/YYYY to YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00.000Z, so that my data will be compatible with my javascript file where I want to add my data.

I want my list to be shown as：

```
rnow = 
[{'date': '2020-01-02T00:00:00.000Z', 'value': 13}, 
{'date': '2020-01-03T00:00:00.000Z', 'value': 2}, 
{'date': '2020-01-06T00:00:00.000Z', 'value': 5},
...
{'date': '2020-01-07T00:00:00.000Z', 'value': 6}]
```

I tried so many methods but can only convert them into `2020-01-02 00:00:00` but not `2020-01-02T00:00:00.000Z`. Please advise what should I do

Comment: You should provide the code you used to produce the dictionary and the original data. It will probably be easier to do the conversion there.

Comment: It's from a google sheet and I am not able to convert it there. Is there any other ways I could do?

Comment: Why did you add `javascript`, `jquery` (, `panda`) as tags? They are not relevant for this question.

Comment: Because YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00.000Z is a `javascript` format. `Pandas` is the package I used to create my data and it has some ways to convert the dates(But I didn't find the one I'm looking for)  `jquery` is the js library that I may change something there so that my date format can be accepted

Comment: No, `YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00.000Z` is not a JavaScript format, it is according the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`isoformat` function](https://pythontic.com/datetime/datetime/isoformat) of Python's builtin `datetime` package:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timezone
formatted = datetime.strptime('01/02/2020', '%m/%d/%Y', tzInfo=timezone.utc).isoformat()

formatted
# Output: '2020-01-02T00:00:00+00:00'
```

Note that Python doesn't support the `Z` suffix for UTC timezone, instead it will be `+00:00` which is according to ISO 8601 as well and should parse in other code just fine.

If this is a problem, you can omit the timezone and instead manually put a `Z` there:

```py
from datetime import datetime
formatted = datetime.strptime('01/02/2020', '%m/%d/%Y').isoformat() + 'Z'

formatted
# Output: '2020-01-02T00:00:00Z'
```

Alternatively (in a more "manual" approach), you could format the date using `strftime`:

```py
from datetime import datetime
formatted = datetime.strptime('01/02/2020', '%m/%d/%Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%dT00:00:00Z')

formatted
# Output: '2020-01-02T00:00:00Z'
```

Comment: Thank you I'll try that! but how should I apply it with my list of dictionaries? I'm new to Python, please kindly advise

Comment: You loop through the list and replace your item's `date` value for the formatted version. Look into how loops, arrays and dictionaries work in Python if this is confusing.

Comment: I tried the following codes to do the loop in my list: 
`def new_date(date):
    return datetime.strptime('date', '%m/%d/%Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%dT00:00:00Z')

for i in range (len(rnow)):
    rnow[i]['date'] = new_date(rnow[i]['date'])`  
 but I got the error message: ` 'date' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y'`

Comment: you probably meant `date` and not `'date'` as argument to `strptime`.

Comment: Can you help me with this question: 
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71117001/adding-list-data-in-a-javascript-line-chart-django-project

Answer (score 4):

If you need exact `T00:00:00.000Z` this string after the time, try to use string format after time conversion,

e.g.,

```py
import datetime
# '2020-01-07T00:00:00.000Z'
datetime.datetime.strptime("07/02/2020", '%d/%m/%Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%dT00:00:00.000Z'))
```

How to apply to pandas:

```py
def func(x):
    myDate = x.date
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(myDate, '%d/%m/%Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%dT00:00:00.000Z')


df['new_date'] = df.apply(func, axis=1)
```

Comment: edited according to CherryDT

Answer (score 2):

To make it easy and keeping UTC and since you are using pandas:

```
rnow = [{'date': '01/02/2020', 'value': 13}, 
{'date': '01/03/2020', 'value': 2}, 
{'date': '01/06/2020', 'value': 5},
{'date': '01/07/2020', 'value': 6}]

def get_isoformat(date):
    return pd.to_datetime(date, dayfirst=False, utc=True).isoformat()
for i in range (len(rnow)):
    rnow[i]['date'] = get_isoformat(rnow[i]['date'])
rnow
```

which outputs:

```
[{'date': '2020-01-02T00:00:00+00:00', 'value': 13},
 {'date': '2020-01-03T00:00:00+00:00', 'value': 2},
 {'date': '2020-01-06T00:00:00+00:00', 'value': 5},
 {'date': '2020-01-07T00:00:00+00:00', 'value': 6}]
```

in fact, you probably want to consider using the function `get_isoformat()` applied to your dataframe for simplicity. Also, if you use `utc=None` will get rid of the `+00:00` part in case you don't want it or need it.

### Edit

To get specificly `2020-01-02T00:00:00Z` try:

```
pd.to_datetime(date, dayfirst=False, utc=False).isoformat()+'Z'
```

Comment: Thank you! but the javascript still cannot parse the `2020-01-02T00:00:00+00:00` and it has to be `2020-01-02T00:00:00Z (%Y-%m-%dT00:00:00Z)`. I'm new to python and tried the loop to do that but failed. Could you please show me how to do that?